# Background image not completely filling div

Tags: html, css, background-image, fill

I am creating a contact page and am using div's to show the address and name of each branch for the business. I am using a container div with a background image of the logo and laying text on top of the div with the address. The problem is the background image is not filling the entire div, even when I set the width and height of the div to the image.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="divContactImg">
  <div class="branchHeader">Durban</div>
  <div class="branchText">82 Joe Slovo Street</div>
  <div class="branchText">Durban</div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.divContactImg {
background-image: url('http://image.png');
width:225px;
height:80px;
border-left: thin solid #333;
border-top: thin solid #333;
border-right: thin solid maroon;
border-bottom: thin solid maroon;
float:left;
text-align:left;
margin-left: 5px;
border-radius:5px;
}                

.branchHeader {
font-size: 24px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 5px;
text-transform:uppercase;

}

.branchText {
font-size: 12px;
color:#cecece;
margin-left: 10px;
text-transform:uppercase;
```

}

My image is of size 225 x 80 pixels however when it renders there it adds an extra two pixels to the height and width, and looks like there is a 2 pixel difference inside the top and left side of the div, almost as if there is some padding being applied

Comment: I tried your code and its working fine. I used an image of the same size and replace your url with mine. http://jsfiddle.net/appleBud/28CEE/3/

Comment: Works in latest Firefox and IE: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nunzabar/cQa6c/1/). Are you sure your image does not have a 2px border/padding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use :

```
background-size: cover;
```

to make your image fill the background of its parent.

Example in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CztS6/1/

Answer (score 2):

you need add `background-size:cover;` or `contain`

```
.divContactImg {
background-image: url('http://image.png');
width:225px;
height:80px;
border-left: thin solid #333;
border-top: thin solid #333;
border-right: thin solid maroon;
border-bottom: thin solid maroon;
float:left;
text-align:left;
margin-left: 5px;
border-radius:5px;
background-size: cover; /**add this**/
}
```

contain - Scales the image proportionally so that the picture is entirely fit into the block.

cover - Scales the image proportionally so that its width or height equal to the width or height of the block.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use `contain` and the background image is not the exact size of the div, the image will try to repeat its self to fill the remaining space proportionally. This is probably not desired, and looks a little funny. fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CztS6/2/